# How can i fetch the error from the firebase backend?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on the forgot password function of my system. Since firebase have it's own backend auth, i wanted to catch the error from firebase and populate it inside the modal.

**Below you can see my forgot_password.js**

[image: This is the code.]

**I wanted to fetch any error firebase auth would give me.**

[image]

Comment: Your current code doesn't catch the error given by firebase?

Comment: Yes, firebase gives the error via Alert.

I wanted to catch the error in order to use to other element such as p tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use await with `catch()` like that. Try using `try...catch`

```js
const handleResetPassword = (e) =? {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    resetPassword(email);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};
```